# Implementing Facebook wishlist tutorial Application Does Not Own Action Type Error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

I am working through the Facebook Wishlist app for Android. When I attempt to add my custom object to the Facebook graph the API returns the following error:

```
  {
     "error: {
      "type": "OAuthExeption",
      "message":"(#100)
     Application does not own
     230752723668296 action type"
      }
     }
```

I haven't been able to find any specific documentation on this particular error. Are there any Facebook developers out there who may be able to help me interpret this.

I should also mention that I already have a working example of this app running without errors (I am trying to duplicate it so I can tweak it with out fear of losing work). I have tried changing the name of the Action but this makes no difference. Below is the snippet of the Android code where it adds the item to the Facebook time line. This is however a small piece of the over all puzzle as there are three sides to this project (Facebook, My Server, and Android)

```
 public void addToTimeline() {
       dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Wishlist.this,    "",getString(R.string.adding_to_timeline), true, true);
    /*
     * Create Product URL
     */
       String productURL = HOST_SERVER_URL + HOST_PRODUCT_URI;
       Bundle productParams = new Bundle();
       productParams.putString("name", mProductName);
       productParams.putString("image", mProductImageName);
       productURL = productURL + "?" + Util.encodeUrl(productParams);

    Bundle wishlistParams = new Bundle();

    if(mPlacesAvailable) {
        try {
            wishlistParams.putString("place", mPlacesJSONArray.getJSONObject(mPlacesListSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getString("id"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {}
    }
    wishlistParams.putString("wishlist", WISHLIST_OBJECTS_URL[mWishlistSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);
    wishlistParams.putString("product", productURL);
    wishlistParams.putString("image", mProductImageURL);
    //TODO
    //put the app's namespace and 'add_to' action here
    Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/wishlisteight:adding_to", wishlistParams, "POST", new addToTimelineListener(), null);
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code to help explain what you're doing and how you're doing it? and OAuchException is an exception thrown by a module, OpenAuth, basically saying that you don't have permission to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your response David. Please see the edits above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*I should also mention that I already have a working example of this app running without errors (I am trying to duplicate it so I can tweak it with out fear of losing work)*"

That action is specific to an app id.  When you made the duplicate of your code, did you use the same app id or create a new one?  If you created a new app id, you will need to register actions for the new app just like you did with the first app.

Comment: I used the same set of steps to create both apps. These steps included creating a new Facebook App (along with a new Facebook app ID) and creating Action Types in the 'Edit Open Graph' section for that app. Not sure what more I can do to "register" the Action type with the app. Also Note if I type anything other than 'adding_to' (which is the name of my action type) in the Android code I get a different error saying it does not recognize the action. So it does seems to be recognizing "adding_to" as some how associated with the app.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was creating my Action by pushing the "Create new action type" button in the Open Graph editor. What I needed to do was create my action by clicking "getting started' under the Open Graph header and creating my action that way. Thanks every for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you got that figured out.  But seems like facebook has room for improvement there.

Answer (score 2):

I encountererd this error (#100 Application does not own action type) when using the Graph API Explorer tool to post an action to my app's timeline. Here is a brief summary of the values I had entered when encountering this error and how I resolved the issue. Fyi, my app is called 'recipestogo'. The action I defined for my app is called 'cook', and the associated object is called 'recipe'.

**Values I entered into Open Graph API:**

Chose 'Post' from the drop-down

https://graph.facebook.com/me/recipestogo:cook?recipe=https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html

**Error encountered:**

## 100 Application does not own action type

**Resolution:**
At the top, right of the API Graph Explorer tool, there is a drop-down next to Application. It had been set by default to Graph API Explorer. Changing this from Graph API Explorer to RecipesToGo resolved the issue and I was able to successfully post to my app's timeline.