# publish actions to facebook using open graph api and C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am getting the following error while publishing the facebook action using open graph api,

**(Exception - #1611072) The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: post.**

The actions are properly mapped to object in facebook app dashboard and i also tested the open grap object  (my web page) in the debugger and there are no warnings.The meta tags in the page has been set properly.

I am using C# for publishing the actions.

Code follows:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("XXX");
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                     {
                                         {"og:type", "testnamespace:post"},{"og:url","http://test.sitename.com/postdetails/3247/Hello-ktm"},
                                         {"og:title", "test post"},
                                         {
                                             "og:image",
                                             "http://cdn.test.com/842-ff7c1e64-8d6f-4989-bf77-1a1f1520b39e_th.png"
                                             }
                                     };  
var response = fb.Post("me/testnamespace:share", parameters);
```

Please help.Its urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At least one of the following properties must be specified: post.

Looks like the name of your object you connected the action with is `post`.

So you will also have to give a parameter named `post`, containing the URL to your OG object, when publishing the action.

Comment: The above example requires for me to pass the access token of the application ,but i observed that the access token changes frequently.Is there any other way around to publish actions using facebook open graph api.I tried passing the access token as parameter in the FacebookClient but i got the following error '(OAuthException - #2) An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.'

Comment: Now i getting the following error for the same above code. '(OAuthException) (#100) Application 276304102435847 does not own 175053105965645 action type' ,i have been trying to troubleshoot it for 1day but not successful.

Please suggest on what i can do ?

Thanks,
S.

Comment: Check if the action does indeed belong to that very app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767351/implementing-facebook-wishlist-tutorial-application-does-not-own-action-type-err

Comment: Yes the action does belong to that very app.I have checked it.